# 405 error while using POST method in Spring + google app engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, post, get

Whenever I try to use method post I am getting 405 error. The get method is working properly. I tried changing the type by using ajax. but it didn't work. Please help

```
@Controller
public class PaymentController {
    @Autowired
    private IAccountService accountService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/payment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String returnAccountInformation(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        String email = (String) session.getAttribute("email");
        PlanInfo planInfo = getAccountService().getPlanInfo(email);
        PlanInfoBean planInfoBean = new PlanInfoBean();
        planInfoBean.setPlanName(planInfo.getPlanName());
        planInfoBean.setPlanType(planInfo.getPlanType());
        planInfoBean.setFeatures(planInfo.getFeatures());
        model.addAttribute(IPaymentConstants.PLANINFO2, planInfoBean);
        // System.out.println(session.getAttribute("email"));
        return "AccountDetails";
    }
```

Comment: how you are passing your data?

Comment: looks like you are not sending a post request, check your method type in outgoing request in browser